# Tcpdump ctrl-c sigint in android terminal emulator is not working

Tags: android, tcpdump, packet-capture, terminal-emulator

I run tcpdump on my android phone using "Terminal Emulator app".
My phone is rooted.

I run tcpdump to sniff my wlan0 interface by `#tcpdump -i wlan0`

I have problem with how to end the tcpdump sniffing process. I already searched the answer, but none of them are working for me. I tried to press special keys on the terminal, `Vol-Dn C` to get `CTRL-C` function keys, but the tcpdump still running.

I also tried `Vol-Up .` to get `CTRL-\` but still, tcpdump doesn't stop the process. Why is my Terminal won't send SIGINT to stop the process?

Tcpdump version 4.5.1 and Terminal Emulator version 1.0.7

Comment: If you can open a _second_ terminal, you can use `ps` to get the _pid_ and then `kill` to kill the specific process id of tcpdump...

Comment: Thanks, it works for me. any ideas why is my terminal emulator app won't send the signit using the special keys?